# Ciclo de vida JSF 2

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee

Estoy empezando con JSF2 y primefaces y tengo una duda respecto al ciclo de vida. Lo explico brevemente:
Tengo pagina1.xhtml que contiene una tabla con un listado y unos botones de edición, entre ellos un botón de nuevo (action="pagina2") que apunta a otra pagina que llamaremos pagina2.xhtml donde habrá unos campos para añadir un nuevo registro.
Luego tenemos un bean para la pagina1 que llamaremos BeanPagina1 donde hay un metodo init con la anotación @PostConstruct.

Bien, veamos, si desde el menu principal accedemos a pagina1 el flujo pasa por el metodo init del bean donde se cargan los datos de la tabla y se mostrara dicha pagina.
Ahora, si pulso el botón nuevo de pagina1 veo que también pasa el flujo por el metodo init del Bean a pesar de que el metodo hace referencia a otra pagina. Esto mismo, es lo que no entiendo, es normal que ocurra esto?
También he probado a crear un bean propio para pagina2 que llameremos BeanPagina2 y en él un método (inicio) que retorna un String con el nombre pagina2. Despues en el action del botón de pagina1 poner "#{beanPagina2.inicio()}" . De esta forma ocurre lo mismo, primero pasa por el metodo init (@PostConstruct) de BeanPagina1 y despues ya va al BeanPagina2.
No se si esto es el ciclo de vida correcto. Claro, en mi caso en ese metodo @PostConstruct del BeanPagina1 hago la llamada a la BBDD para la recuperación de los datos de la tabla pero no veo correcto que cadda vez que pulso un botón me vuelva a recuperar los datos de la tabla...

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo con los fragmentos de código relevante? Es difícil seguir lo que dices.

Comment: @Wall75 en la anotación Postcontruct se ejecutan todas las acciones después del constructor ahí solo deben de ir llamadas para llenar tablas o los combos

Comment: @Raul Cacacho eso es lo que hago en el Postconstruct, llenar la tabla que hay en la pagina1.xhtml . lo que pasa que como ese metodo se ejecuta más veces de las que considero necesarias (que es lo que comento anteriormente), me gustaría evitar todas esas llamadas a la BBDD.

Comment: @Wall75 si editas la pregunta puedo hacerte un ejemplo

Comment: @Wall75 puedes validar la lista mientras este vacía entre a llenarla otra vez

Comment: @RaulCacacho No entiendo lo que quieres decir cuando pones "si editas la pregunta puedo hacerte un ejemplo". En cuando al otro comentario siempre que se ejecuta el metodo Postconstruct la lista llega vacia

Comment: No siempre va llegar vacia solo la primera vez depende del alcance q le hayas dado al magedBean

Answer (score 0):

Hasta donde yo sé, lo que dices es el ciclo de JSF.

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un proyecto muy similar en el que la sesión se crea por cada Request (Un verdadero asco porque tenemos que guardar el estado de todos los elementos que queremos mostrar).

Como tú tambien tenemos que hacer varios accesos a la base de datos, y por cada vez que se recarga la página los haría de nuevo, por eso lo que yo hice fue guardar el estado de los elementos que me traigo de la base de datos y si la página se recarga lo primero que hago es comprobar que si la lista de elementos viene vacía, entonces haría las consultas a la base de datos, sino cargaría directamente los valores de la lista.

Comment: Lo de guardar los elementos no lo veo muy elegante ni efectivo ya que lo que yo muestro es una tabla donde se recuperan todos los elementos de la tabla de la BBDD, guardar todo ese listado creo que iría en contra del buen rendimiento de la app. Y utilizar bean con ambito de session, según he leído, tampoco es una practica muy recomendable precisamente por lo mismo, el rendimiento

Comment: Me choca porque cuando hago lo inverso, es decir desde pagina2 ir a pagina1, el ciclo no pasa por el bean de la pagina2, si no que va directamente al método init del beanPagina1. Bueno, si ese es el comportamiento habitual, tendré que buscar alguna solución, se me ocurre trabajar con parámetros para saber de donde se viene y de ese modo saber si debo recuperar los datos de la BBDD o no

Comment: Coincido contigo en que no es la mejor práctica, pero si me dicen que lo haga así en el trabajo, tengo que hacerlo :/

Comment: te entiendo.....